# Having Difficulties Implementing Bullet/Enemy Collision Detection In A Simple Shooter (C# 2010/XNA 4.0)

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, collision-detection

Firstly, I would like to say sorry for making another thread asking the same question (more or less), but I am desperate for an answer and the other thread went dead.

I am currently working on a project for school in which I am attempting to make a simple 2d shooter. Problem is, I don't know how to implement collision detection between my two lists (being bullets and enemies as stated in title). I am very new to programming and have been using various tutorials as a guide, some tutorials say to use a nested for loop and if statement while I have seen others using an if statement, oh and I'm using the rectangle collision method not the pixel by pixel one I think it was called. Thanks in advance! :)

Here is my code:

**Main:**

```
namespace Software_Design_Major_Project
```

{

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Texture2D ship; // Declaring the sprite
    Vector2 shipposition = Vector2.Zero; // Creating a vector for the sprite.

    List<bullets> bullets = new List<bullets>(); // a list is created here so that there can be multiple copies of this item at once without writing the extra code.
    Texture2D texture;

    KeyboardState pastkey;

    //bullet sound effect.
    SoundEffect effect;

    List<enemies> Enemies = new List<enemies>();       
    Random random2 = new Random();        

    float spawn = 0;

    public enum GameState 
    {
        MainMenu,            
        Playing,

    }
    GameState CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;

    int screenWidth = 600, screenHeight = 480;

    cButton play;                    

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        //changes width of screen to 600px.
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 600;

    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
         // This statement positions the ship.
        ship = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship"); // Loads the ship into the memory.
        shipposition = new Vector2((graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2) - (ship.Width / 2), 420); 
        // loads bullet sprite
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet");

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;            

        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        IsMouseVisible = true;

        play = new cButton(Content.Load<Texture2D>("play"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        play.setPosition(new Vector2(225, 220));

        effect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("laser");            


    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        spawn += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        // spawns enemy every second.
        foreach (enemies enemy in Enemies)
            enemy.update(graphics.GraphicsDevice);


        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:

                if (play.isClicked == true)
                    CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;

                play.Update(mouse);

                break;

            case GameState.Playing:

                if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.E))
                {
                    Exit();
                }

                break;


        }

        // Allows the ship to move left and stops the ship going off the screen.          
        if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && shipposition.X >= 0)
        {
            shipposition.X -= 7;
        }// same as above except for the right direction.
        if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) && shipposition.X < ((graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width) - (ship.Width)))
        {
            shipposition.X += 7;
        }

        // this prevents the player from holding down space to spam bullets.
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && pastkey.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
        {
            bullets bullet = new bullets(texture);
            // the ships coordinates are gathered from the top left hand corner of the sprites rectangle therefore 'new Vector2(shipposition.X + 32, shipposition.Y)' had to
            // be added rather than just = 'shipposition' to avoid having the bullets shoot from the wing. 
            bullet.position = new Vector2(shipposition.X + 32, shipposition.Y);
            bullets.Add(bullet);
            effect.Play();

        }


        pastkey = Keyboard.GetState();

        //calls upon the update method from the bullets class.

        foreach (bullets bullet in bullets)
            bullet.update();


            LoadEnemies();
        base.Update(gameTime);


    }       

        public void LoadEnemies() 
        {
            int randX = random2.Next(10, 540);

            if (spawn <= 1) 
            {
                spawn = 0;
                //limits amount of enemies on screen to 5.
                if (Enemies.Count() < 5)
                    Enemies.Add(new enemies(Content.Load<Texture2D>("enemy"), new Vector2(randX, -100)));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Enemies.Count; i++) 
            {
                if (!Enemies[i].enemyVisble)
                {
                    //removes the enemies when they go off screen.
                    Enemies.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }

            }
        }



        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            // calls draw method in bullets class
            foreach (bullets bullet in bullets)
            {
                bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
            spriteBatch.Draw(ship, shipposition, Color.White); // draws ship sprite 



            switch (CurrentGameState)
            {
                case GameState.MainMenu:
                    play.draw(spriteBatch);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("menu"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);

                    break;

                case GameState.Playing:


                    break;


            }



            foreach (enemies enemy in Enemies)
            {
                enemy.draw(spriteBatch);
            }

             spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }            


}
```

}

**Bullets Class:**

```
namespace Software_Design_Major_Project
```

{

```
      class bullets // A new class needs to be created to allow for bullets.
      {
            public Texture2D texture;
            public Vector2 position;     
            public bool isvisible;                                  

            public bullets(Texture2D newtexture) 
            {
                texture = newtexture;
                isvisible = false;
            }

            public void update() 
            {
                position.Y -= 3; // velocity of the bullet                    

            } 


            public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) 
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
            }
      }
```

}

**Enemies Class:**

```
namespace Software_Design_Major_Project
{
    public class enemies
    {
        public Texture2D enemyTexture;
        public Vector2 enemyPosition;        
        public bool enemyVisble = true;
        public float enemyMoveSpeed;
        public int Value;
        Random random = new Random();
        int randY; 

        public enemies (Texture2D newEnemyTexture, Vector2 newEnemyPosition) 
        {
            enemyTexture = newEnemyTexture;
            enemyPosition = newEnemyPosition;
            randY = random.Next(1, 4);
            enemyMoveSpeed = randY;
            enemyVisble = true;                        
            Value = 100;            

        }

        public void update(GraphicsDevice graphics) 
        {
            enemyPosition.Y += enemyMoveSpeed;

            if (enemyPosition.Y > 500)
                enemyVisble = false;             

        }

        public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) 
        {

            spriteBatch.Draw(enemyTexture, enemyPosition, Color.White);            
            enemyVisble = true;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do it... one of them maybe add a radio property to enemies and bullets....

```
  for (int bi=0; bi<bullets.count; )
  {
      bool should_destroy_bullet = false;
      Bullet b = bullets[bi];
      for (int ei=0; ei<enemies.count; )
      {
         Enemy e = ememies[ei];
         if (b.radio + e.radio < Vector2.Distance(b.Pos, e.Pos))  // Check collision
         {
             e.Died();
             enemies[ei] = enemies[enemies.Count-1];
             enemies.RemoveAt(enemies.Count-1);
             should_destroy_bullet = true;  // This lets a bullet kill more than one enemy
         } else ei++;
      }

      if (should_destroy_bullet) {
            b.Died();
            bullets[bi] = bullets[bullets.count-1];
            bullets.RemoveAt(bullets.count-1);
      } else bi++;
  }
```

Or you can build a rectangle for each sprite and check if they intersects....

```
   if (b.Bounds.Intersects(e.Bounds)) ....
```

Comment: thanks blau, so does this go in my main's update method? How do i go about adding the rectangles (i know that you need rectangle = new rectangle(blablabla);)

Comment: yes... if you want working with rectangles... each time you update the sprite position... you have to update the rectangle... Rectangle Bounds = (spr.X - size.x/2, spr.Y - size.y/2, size.x, size,y)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time making a 2d game. at the moment i have declared my bullet rectangle in my "Class bullets" as  public Rectangle bulletRectangle
                {
                    get { return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, bulletTexture.Width, bulletTexture.Height); }
                }  is this the right way of doing this and where do I go after doing this? whenever I go to use this rectangle using the "intersects" term I get the error: "enemyRectangle does not exist in the current context".

Comment: enemies and bullets shares a lot of funcionality, the common way of doing it, is declaring a sprite class with position, bounds, texture2d and a draw method, and inherit bullet and enemy from sprite...

Answer (score 0):

The Pythagorean theorem could work for you.(A squared plus B squared = C squared)
Make your players and enemies have a radius.Put this in your constructor.

```
public float radius = 15;
```

Put the following in a update void/subclass so that it happens every second.
Make a float the X location of your player and subtract the X location of the bullet. Square it.

```
float XDist = Math.Pow(player1.location.X - bullet.location.X,2);
```

Make a float the Y location of your player and subtract the Y location of the `bullet.Square` it.

```
float YDist = Math.Pow(player1.location.X - bullet.location.X,2);
```

Make a float to figure out the square root of the sum of Xdist and Ydist.

```
float actualDist = Math.Sqrt(Xdist + Ydist);
```

Now if the radius of your player is less than the distance between the player and the bullet, the bullet has hit the player.

```
if(actualDist < radius)
   bullethit == true;
```